# What kind of surface is this?

Tags: geometry, surfaces

I'm not a math guru, but I'm just fascinated by it, so I'm sorry if my questions are only out of curiosity and are not high level.

In some contemporary art website, I have found this image:

[image: surface and sculpture]

In the right side there is a sculpture, and in the left side there is a surface. What kind of surface is it? How is it reproducible with some mathematical tool like [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)?

Comment: Where did you find the plot ?

Comment: It's some kind of three dimensional mapping of a wireless local area network. Similar gibberish can be found at http://www.peterjellitsch.com/tag/model/.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici a google image search shows that it comes from this [site](http://www.peterjellitsch.com/tag/process/page/2/). It seems to be a plot showing some sort of WLAN activities.

Comment: Start typing "plot3d Sin[x+y]Cos[x-y]" or "plot3d Sin[x+y^2]" and play with coefficients and/or exponents. You will have a lot of fun

Comment: By the way, I find the function much more beautiful than the sculture. What about you ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: yes, that's why I have asked it here : )

Comment: Anyway, it does not seems to me a periodic function

Answer (score 4):

From the looks of the plot on the left, this seems to be what MATLAB calls the [`peaks()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/peaks.html) function:

$$\begin{align*}\mathtt{peaks}(x)=&3(1-x)^2\exp\left(-x^2-(y+1)^2\right)-10 \left(\frac{x}{5}-x^3-y^5\right) \exp\left(-x^2-y^2\right)-\\&\frac13\exp\left(-(x+1)^2-y^2\right)\end{align*}$$

A look at the M-file for this function tells me that Cleve Moler himself included it in MATLAB. This is a function often used in that program to demonstrate optimization methods.

Just to be ornery, here is a surface plot and contour plot of `peaks()` in *Mathematica*:
[image: MATLAB'S peaks()]

Comment: So is it just meant to look like a random surface?

Comment: It seems so, yes.